# How to shuffle multiple values in JavaScript ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, ternary-operator

I have successfully implemented multiple condition ternary operator to shuffle class between Horizontal and vertical as follows:

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#my_div")
     .removeClass("horizontal vertical")
     .addClass( ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gray'].indexOf(my_color) != -1 ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical');
});
</script>
```

my_color may have one value at the time from red,blue,green,grey white and black. As stated above class `horizontal` set for first 4 `my_color` value and `vertical` for other. Now I want to add and remove third class `elliptical` where horizontal,vertical and elliptical set for 2 values of my_color only,. how can I modify my above script or can implement the same using switch statement?

Comment: SO horizontal pulls from the pool of options red/blue/green/grey, where vertical pulls from the pool of white, black?

Comment: Yes it is. Now I want Horizontal from red/blue  vertical from green/grey and elliptical from black/white.

Comment: Actually I shuffled two class for multiple conditions, so I want to shuffle multiple classes. simply we can get it through if else statement.But I don't want to write lengthy code with if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) with a switch to easily add/remove classes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gray'];
   $("#my_div")
      .toggleClass('horizontal', colors.indexOf(my_color) != -1)
      .toggleClass('vertical', colors.indexOf(my_color) == -1)
      .toggleClass('elliptical', [colors[0], colors[1]].indexOf(my_color) != -1);
});
```

First class is added if color matches array and removed if not, second is opposite, and third is added if color matches first or second array value. array.indexOf is not supported in all browsers and you should probably use a polyfill.

Comment: This is nice, but then elliptical get set along with horizontal as well as with vertical for [colors[0], colors[1]].

Comment: @galexy - yes, I kind of thought that was the point, if it's not a regular if/else is probably simpler.

Comment: Then How can I write simple switch statement which removes current class and adds class relative to condition set. I think switch is better if we have to shuffle between three css class for pool of multiple values as condition.